# Return method results and supply them as parameters to methods that execute in a chain

Tags: java, completable-future

The following code executes 3 methods sequentially using `CompletableFuture`.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// Various handlers
ModelHandler modelHandler = new ModelHandler();
PermissionHandler permissionHandler = new PermissionHandler();
RemoteClient remoteClient = new RemoteClient();


Runnable getFacadeMetadata = () -> modelHandler.getMetadata("myMethod");
Runnable isUserAuthorized = () -> permissionHandler.isUserAuthorized("user");
Runnable invoke = () -> remoteClient.invoke();

CompletableFuture.runAsync(getMetadata, executor)
    .thenRunAsync(isUserAuthorized, executor)
    .thenRunAsync(invoke, executor);
```

Currently they don't return values and supply them as parameters to the next calls.

How should the `CompletableFuture` chain be written so that the first two methods can return data to be consumed by later methods?

Example:

```
String metadata = modelHandler.getMetadata("myMethod");
boolean authorized = permissionHandler.isUserAuthorized("user", metadata); // metadata passed

remoteClient.invoke(metadata, authorized); // metadata and authorized passed
```

Comment: really? `thenApplyAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just had 2 methods then it would be very easy to pass the return value of the first to the second ofcourse

```
Supplier<String> getFacadeMetadata = () -> modelHandler.getMetadata("myMethod");
Function<String, Object[]> isUserAuthorized = (metadata) -> permissionHandler.isUserAuthorized("user", metadata);
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getFacadeMetadata, executor).thenApplyAsync(isUserAuthorized, executor);
```

But you wish to pass the return value of the first method (metadata) to the third function and I don't think that can be done directly. You may call getMetadata again or change return of isAuthorized to array, returning both metadata and boolean, neither a clean approach I'm afraid. So below is what I would propose

```
Supplier<String> getFacadeMetadata = () -> modelHandler.getMetadata("myMethod");
Consumer<String> invoke = (metadata) -> {
    boolean isAuth = permissionHandler.isUserAuthorized("user", metadata);
    remoteClient.invoke(metadata, isAuth);
};

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getFacadeMetadata, executor)
        .thenAcceptAsync(invoke, executor);
```